# How to make the title bold?

Tags: qt, qt4, symbian, nokia

In `QMessageBox` how can I make the title text bold?
Here is the sample code, which I am using to disply a messagebox:

```
int ret = QMessageBox::warning(this, tr("My Application"),
          tr("document has been modified.\n"
          "Do you want to save your changes?"),
          QMessageBox::Save | QMessageBox::Discard
          | QMessageBox::Cancel,
          QMessageBox::Save);
```

I just want `tr("My Application")` to be bold, and rest to be in normal font.
How can I do that?
By default I am getting the normal font for both title and descriptive text.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add some HTML-like formatting to the message box contents, i.e. :

```
// ...
"Do you want to save your <b>changes</b>?"),
// ...
```

I do not have access to S60 environment to check if it works for message box title too. It doesn't work on Windows, but hey, it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible since most window managers do not allow rich text inside the window title.